# How to keep content on page on new page load

Tags: html, http

I want to know, how we can do the page reload but while loading the page we keep some conten on page visiable.

In real senario, google or facebook load new page or chages some part of the page(not using the ajax) but there header or footer are not get  change means stick to page and it visible through-out the process to page load start and end.

Can anyone tell me how it has to be done?

Answer (score 0):

well, your examples don't reload page. They load new content with AJAX, so while loading you can execute your scipts and display current content. After you can append new blocks to page and change url using HTML5 History API.